# Snowflake: How can I get the size of an array in bytes?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, how can I get the size of an array in bytes?  I don't see a function to do so in their documentation. The closest I have found are the [LENGTH/LEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/length.html) and [OCTET_LENGTH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/octet_length.html) functions, which only apply to strings or binary types.

I also do not think [ARRAY_SIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_size.html) is the correct function here either, that returns the number of items in the array if I am not mistaken.

I specifically would like to know for the [ARRAY data type](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#array)

Comment: There are many ways to measure the size of things - depends on context. Can you add in what context you need this information?

Comment: We are using a tool that limits results' column sizes to 1MB.  And I have a query that contains a column value that will vary quite a bit and grow/shrink over time.  I need a way to return in my results the current size of that column's value to view how close I am to that 1MB limit.  That column's data type is an array.

Comment: Oh, I see. So then the most important question is "how does said tool measure the size of an array" - which depends on the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT LEN(ARRAY_TO_STRING(array,''))
...
```

This turns the array into a string with a blank delimiter and then provides the length of that string.

Comment: Is the size in bytes of the converted string always guaranteed to be equal to the size in bytes of the array?

Comment: It'll be the same as far as characters, but are you referring to the storage bytes?  If so, no, compression on an array and a string will likely be different from a storage perspective.